# Can't use randint() directly in the .format() string?

Tags: python, random

Complete beginner here.

I'm making a short game where one of the two players is randomly chosen to start the game:

```
from random import randint
player1 = input("First player, enter your name: ")
player2 = input("Second player, enter your name: ")

print("{randint(0,1)} will go first".format(name1, name2))
```

I want randint() to choose either player1 or player2, but I'm getting a TypeError. If I were to put either 0 or 1 into the {} instead of randint(0, 1) it works fine. Why doesn't this work? What other options are there besides an if/elif statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `randint(0,1)` as an index to get the player name

```
players=[player1,player2]    
print("{} will go first".format(players[randint(0,1)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Is there any reason randint can't be used inside of the curly braces?

Comment: You can't execute code in python by placing it in a string like that.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't quite how the string format method works, the numbers you pass in like `{0}` and `{1}` serve as indices in the things you pass into the string in the `.format(0th item here, 1st item here...etc.)` call. So if you want your random integer to show up you should do something like:

```
print("{0} will go first".format(randint(0,1)))
```